# Are these two set Lebesgue-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B \subseteq [0,1]\times[0,1]$ be defined as,
$$ A= \bigcup_{x\in[0,1]}\{(x,q)\mid q\leq x,q \in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\} $$
$$B=\bigcup_{y\in[0,1]}\{(q,y)\mid q\leq y,q \in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\}$$

Are these two set Lebesgue measurable? I think by symmtery $A$ is measurable iff $B$ is measurable. But I can't work with any of them. Please help!

Comment: First show: if $q \in [0,1]$ is a rational number, then the set $[q,1]\times \{q\}$ is measurable.

Comment: yes, it is one dimensional set, so has measure 0 and thus measurable. But how does this help me?

Comment: Oh yes, I have got it, A is countable union of those sets and hence has measure 0! Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually this method shows more: your sets are even Borel sets.